# Evaluate the limit $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\gamma + \log_2(x + \gamma)}{\gamma + \sqrt{x +\gamma} - \sqrt{x}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I need to find out whether
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\gamma + \log_2(x + \gamma)}{\gamma + \sqrt{\gamma + x} - \sqrt{x}} = 0.
$$
My best effort was:
$$
\frac{2}{\ln 2} \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x + \gamma} - \sqrt{x} - \gamma / \sqrt{x}}.
$$
I don't know how to continue from here. Any help?

Comment: Clarification question: I'm fairly certain it is but just want to double check that $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant?

Comment: Use$$\sqrt{\gamma+x}-\sqrt x=\frac{\gamma}{\sqrt{\gamma+x}+\sqrt x}$$to figure out the limit of the denominator.

Comment: @AndrewL It's not; just an arbitrary constant.

Answer (score 2):

**Method 1** As David wrote in the comments, using the identity
$$\sqrt{x + \gamma} - \sqrt{x} = \frac{\gamma}{\sqrt{x + \gamma} + \sqrt{x}}$$ we see that the limit of the denominator as $x \to \infty$ is $$\require{cancel}\lim_{x \to \infty} \left(\gamma + \frac{\gamma}{\sqrt{x + \gamma} + \sqrt{x}}\right) = \gamma + \cancelto{0}{\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\gamma}{\sqrt{x + \gamma} + \sqrt{x}}} = \gamma .$$

> On the other hand, as $x \to \infty$, the numerator approaches $+\infty$---it is $O(\log x)$---so the original limit is $\pm\infty$ where $\pm$ is the sign of $\gamma$.

**Method 2** Rationalizing the expression gives
$$\frac{(\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{x + \gamma} - \gamma)(2 \sqrt{x} + \gamma - 1) (\log_2(x + \gamma) + \gamma)}{4 \gamma x - (\gamma - 1)^2 \gamma} ,$$

The denominator is a linear function of $x$, so we multiply the numerator and denominator by $\frac{1}{x}$ and separately take the limits of the two.

> The numerator approaches $\infty$ (it is $O(\log x)$), whereas the denominator approaches $4 \gamma$, so the limit of the ratio (which is thus also $O(\log x)$) approaches $\pm\infty$, where $\pm$ is the sign of $\gamma$.

**Remark** A perhaps more interesting problem is to evaluate the limit of the original quantity times $\frac{1}{\log_2 x}$, which is finite but nonzero.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative by [binomial first order approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_approximation) for $x$ large

$$\sqrt{\gamma + x} = \sqrt{ x}\sqrt{1+\frac{\gamma} x}\approx \sqrt{ x}+\frac{\gamma}{2\sqrt x}$$

therefore

$$ \frac{\gamma + \log_2(x + \gamma)}{\gamma + \sqrt{\gamma + x} - \sqrt{x}} \approx\frac{\gamma + \log_2(x + \gamma)}{\gamma +\frac{\gamma}{2\sqrt x}} \to \operatorname{sign}(\gamma)\;\infty$$